# Cabal failed to install 'unix'

Tags: cabal

it failed to install unix.

C:\Windows\system32>cabal install hdevtools
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring unix-2.6.0.1...
cabal: The package has a './configure' script. This requires a Unix
compatibility toolchain such as MinGW+MSYS or Cygwin.
Failed to install unix-2.6.0.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hdevtools-0.1.0.5 depends on unix-2.6.0.1 which failed to install.
unix-2.6.0.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was: 
ExitFailure 1

C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: As the error message says, hdevtools depends on the "unix" package which won't install in Windows. Try installing cygwin as it suggests. You can probably get by without hdevtools though. ghc-mod does the same thing, more or less (and may be OK on windows, I haven't tried).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you may use this fork https://github.com/mvoidex/hdevtools.